# Can't create an array of list objects

Tags: c#, collections

I have a line of code like this:

```
List<string>[] apples = new List<string>()[2];
```

Its purpose is simply to create an array of List objects.  When I try to compile my code, the above line generates this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List[]

I haven't been able to find much on the subject of creating an array of List objects (actually only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317222/array-of-lists-throws-nullreferenceexception) thread), maybe because no search engines will search for brackets.

Is the only way to create a collection of Lists to put them in another list, like below?

```
List<List<string>> apples = new List<List<string>>(); //I've tried this and it works as expected
```

Thanks for any suggestions, I'm really just curious as to why the first line of code (the List[] example) doesn't work.

Comment: Simple mistake, remove the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't think to try that.

Comment: Make it interesting, ask why the error message is so lousy.

Comment: Haha, actually I was trying to go through the error message logically in my head before I posted this question....It didn't make a whole lot of sense to me, but I figured it was because I'm a newbie.  Though I think if I asked why it's such a lousy error message, no one would have the answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this.  The syntax would be:

```
List<string>[] apples = new List<string>[2];
```

Note that this only allocates an array of references - you'll need to actually construct the individual list elements before you use them:

```
List<string>[] apples = new List<string>[2];
apples[0] = new List<string>();
apples[1] = new List<string>();
```

Alternatively, you can use the collection initialization syntax (works well for small numbers of fixed elements), ie:

```
List<string>[] apples = new[] { new List<string>(), new List<string>() };
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the 'collection initialization syntax,' I can see how that would be useful.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
List<string>[] apples = new List<string>[2];
```

You do the initialization of each list afterwards:

```
apples[0] = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        var listArray = new List<string>[2];
        for (var i = 0; i < listArray.Length; i++)
        {
            listArray[i] = new List<string>();
        }
```